# What are the data mining platform does Space agencies such as Nasa or SpaceX use?

Tags: data-transmission, python

What are the data mining platform does Space agencies such as Nasa or SpaceX use? Just a few would be helpful. This is for data mining and data analysis purpose.

In general, i was looking something like R, Python or SQL.

Comment: Possibly worth clarifying, are you interested in engineering work or science? SpaceX, Boeing and NASA do engineering work that would involve data analysis about launch systems and hardware, but from the phrasing of your question are you more interested in the analysis of space probe results? In which case that is often done by the organizations outside NASA that provided individual instruments. There is probably no single answer to this question.

Comment: @GremlinWranger - Thanks for the notes.. ; I come from programming background and i am interested in the engineering work. My interest are towards the data. Source of data, mode of transfer, data storage and finally how to analyze the data from which we received. Space agencies are following this process. I am in a very early stage on collecting these details

Comment: @GremlinWranger - If you have some suggestions about the companies or instruments handling the space probe results will be helpful for me to study them.

Comment: Boring way to answer your question is via Wikipedia, look at recent probes and find which organisation built it. Then search for papers using data from that instrument and check what process was used. A useful term is 'Principal investigator', who normally is the person who came up with the instrument, and is responsible for it's mission. Research using the data will probably feature their name.

Comment: I agree with you Gremlin, Thank you .. By any chance, i can visit your website or email to be connected and get clarified if any :) -Thanks

Comment: NASA is huge, I'm sure they use *everything*.

Comment: This question is far too broad, and also is partly unanswerable because of ITAR concerns.

Comment: @DavidHammen - Oh woow, I am sorry .. i didnt meant to ask something which shouldn't.. i come from data background.. and so showed interest on this topic..

Comment: NASA directly employs almost 20000 people and employs another 60000 through its contractors. If only 0.1% of those employees use / develop data mining techniques, that makes for 800 data miners at NASA. And that is a ridiculously low estimate. Data mining is used at NASA to help solve a very wide variety of problems. The large number of data miners and the large number of problem domains is what makes this problem overly broad.

Comment: I agree with you, i presume they use  programming languages such as c/c++ or python / fortran  and nothing fancy

Comment: Thank you David, Felt to request  this ..Any third party companies outside of NASA engaged in the data mining as a contract firm with whom i can reach out for a job ?

Answer (score 2):

NASA manages several [repositories of data](https://www.nasa.gov/open/data.html), one of interest is [software](https://code.nasa.gov/#/) which includes things like code for [image processing](https://software.nasa.gov/software/ARC-16053-1) working with [google earth](https://software.nasa.gov/software/LAR-19151-1), A c++ '[mass atrocity predictor](https://community.topcoder.com/longcontest/?module=ViewProblemStatement&rd=15761&pm=12634)' or kernal for code [verification](https://software.nasa.gov/software/ARC-16789-1). In terms of technology used I'd assume space agencies will use pretty much anything (lots of Fortran code there) that has ever existed, and some of their own devising because of the various unique needs.

Comment: Thank you, You mentioned about Image based data - Which is processed through C++ or could be Python to an extent. Second data could be - Signals what are send from Sat's , space vehicles - How this data is analyzed ? Do they have any data mining environment to handle ?  And also, I am surprised to hear about Fortran. I never thought they will have fortran in today's date.

Comment: Suspect Fortran is not used in the analysis any more, but is most likely still in the raw data path to the repository, because these missions fly for decades and you don't break things that work. Possibly worth holding off accepting the answer for at least 24 hours to see if anybody actually working the field posts something authoritve

Comment: Thank you Gremlin Wranger, I will do that.

Comment: I take back. Fortran is still in use. ( https://www.nas.nasa.gov/publications/ams/2015/04-28-15.html )